Why were Lot and his family told not to look back?
While God was destroying Sodom, the angels told Lot and his family: "Flee for your life! Do not look behind you, nor stop anywhere". [Gen. 19:17] But...

וַתַּבֵּ֥ט אִשְׁתּ֖וֹ מֵאַחֲרָ֑יו וַתְּהִ֖י נְצִ֥יב מֶֽלַח׃ -- Lot’s wife looked back, and she thereupon turned into a pillar of salt. [Gen. 19:26]

Why were they not supposed to look back?
Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer [25:11] says that HaShem was there and you die when you see Him.  (But does it turn you into salt?)  Rashi says it's because it's not right that they should witness the doom of the people they knew while they themselves are escaping.  Ramban says it's because the lethal agents (heat, fumes, bacteria, viruses, radiation, etc.) could affect them even from afar.  (But does it make a difference if they hit you in the back?)
I think something is missing because the punishment (death) seems too harsh. The angels did not threaten punishment of any kind.  A warning or an explanation would have been in order.

https://youtu.be/Sqz5dbs5zmo

@shmosel -- "Cool Guys Don't Look At Explosions"?  Sure, but do they turn into salt and die if they do?

I understood the rashi (https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.19.17.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) differently. To me, he seems to bee saying that Lot and his family weren't saved through any merit of their own, rather they sinned with and were just as evil as those being destroyed. Because they deserved that same destruction, it was wrong for them to look at it. The consequence for looking wasn't death, but removal of the undeserved protection that kept them alive.

They weren't "just as evil", but got a pass because some of Abraham's merit rubbed off on them.

You can make an argument that Lot was better than the rest of the people. However, I think his family is just as bad as them and your question was about his wife.

I’ve always thought of looking back / returning to the city as symbolic of a return to sin / his previous way of life. Lot may have been relatively righteous, but it’s not like he regarded the city as evil himself; he likely would have continued living there if God hadn’t destroyed it. Nor did he initially believe that it was so depraved as to deserve destruction - which is why he asked God if he could find so many righteous people to spare the city. He thought he could do so. God agreed so that Lot might come to acknowledge the depravity of the city and leave it behind.

@RyanPierceWilliams 1. Lot didn't argue for Sodom to be saved, that was Avraham. 2. I do think the idea of Lot not leaving Sodom mentally fits really well. He was saved so he could return to Avraham, but he chose to settle elsewhere and commit depraved acts with his daughters.

As you quoted, the Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer teaches us that the intention was to prevent Lot and his family from seeing the shechinah as it descended to destroy Sedom. However, I stumbled upon another explanation from Rabbi David Tzvi Hoffmann (see AlHaTorah):

ויהי כהוציאם וגו' – מכיוון שהוצא מן העיר חרף העדר אמונתו, בחמלת ה',
הרי שלפחות הצלתו מכאן ואילך צריכה להיות בזכות מעשה אמונה. משום כך
נצטווה שלא לעמוד כלל, ואפילו לא להביט אחורה כדי לראות, אם אמנם יבוצע
העונש כפי שנתבשר.
Since Lot was taken out of the city despite his lack of faith, solely due to G-d's compassion, it follows that his salvation from this point onward needed to be earned through an act of faith. For this reason, he was commanded not to stop at all, nor even to look back to see whether the punishment, as foretold, would indeed come to pass.

The Radak also says that by looking back, Lot was giving the impression that he was not sure whether the city was really destroyed:

to ascertain if the city behind him was really being destroyed.

So, if we extrapolate the meaning of the words of R' Hoffmann, we can explain that by looking back, Lot was giving the impression that he lacked faith that G-d would destroy the city due to the sins of it's inhabitants.
The Chida in Pnei David (Bereishis 19:17) hints to us that this posuk means that one should leave a sinning-environment and is instructed not to look back, e.g. one should leave his sins behind and not to stay at that place. By looking back, I think the Chida is learning us that Lot was not ready to "move on" from sinning.

It seems the lack of faith is no so much in the destruction of the city but in the fact that Lot had to dissociate himself from the city and its ways if he wanted to be alive.

I don't understand: it follows that his salvation from this point onward needed to be earned. If the previous acts were unearned, why should the unearned salvation suddenly stop there?

@magicker72 maybe once Hashem grants a person an opportunity, the individual is expected to seize it and prove worthy. The prohibition against looking back or lingering can be seen as a test of Lot's faith and acknowledgment of Hashem's justice. By complying, Lot demonstrates a shift from passive reliance on mercy to active participation in his salvation.

One can answer using the Rashi's comment to Bereshis 19:17:

אל תבט אחריך LOOK NOT BEHIND THEE — You sinned with them but you are being saved through the merit of Abraham. It is not fitting that you should witness their doom whilst you yourself are escaping (Genesis Rabbah 50:11).

The fact, that one needs to have special merit to see the punushment of the wicked people by G-d, we learn from Tehilim 91:8-9:

You will see it with your eyes, you will witness the punishment of the wicked. Because you took Hashem — my refuge, the Most High — as your haven...

The first verse, Tehilim 91:8, talks about seeing punishment, so Rashi there asks:

and...the annihilation Heb. ושלמת, complete destruction. And why?

The answer comes from the following verse Tehilim 91:9, that speaks about great faith of a person:

For you You said, “The Lord is my refuge.” This is an elliptical verse (i.e. it omits words that are obviously understood but must be supplied by the comment to make the sentence grammatically correct). the Most High you made your dwelling. You made the Holy One, blessed be He, the seat of your trust.

The commentary Be'er haTorah (a part of Hoil Moshe) by rabbi Moshe ben Avraham Mat from Przemyśl (a  town in south-eastern Poland) has a long comment on this specific question and he gives several additional reasons.

When analyzing the comment of Rashi, he mentions Noach who was righteous in his generation. At the time to enter the Ark, Hashem closed the door behind Noach and did not let him watch destruction of the evil people. In other words, since even for the righteous Noach there was no permission to stare at the destruction, more so for the controversial person like Lot and his family.

Additionally, R'Moshe mentions 2 practical reasons regarding real danger when looking at the fire:

Ramban on Bereshis 19:17:


Looking upon the atmosphere of a plague and all contagious diseases is very harmful, and they may cleave to him. Even the thought of them is harmful. Therefore, the leper is isolated and dwells alone. (Vayikra 13:40).


The fire of sulfur and salt additionally contained poisonous salt which is extremely dangerous for the eyes (Sodomite salt). The poisonous steams from the fire were were a real danger as they hit the face, but not the back of people running away, even if the wind blew in their direction.

